# Can I use TensorFlow for econometric modelling?

Tags: tensorflow

I have been interested in TensorFlow since its release. I am an applied financial econometrician working with massive datasets. I wonder if I could build econometric models on top of TensorFlow. Is that something that would be feasible? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

I am particularly interested in building parallel and distributed solutions. I am very keen to learn what I can from the machine learning community about running models at scale.  I very much appreciate your input and thoughts! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be **surprised** if there weren't already people trying this around the world.  But this is probably their *secret sauce* so they're not going to publish until they're ready, if at all.

It's totally feasible, but the disadvantages are that none of the tools will work "out of the box".  This is one problem with being on the cutting edge.

The advantages are that TensorFlow is sort of like "assembler code for deep learning", so it's all "in there".  And you're on the cutting edge.

The short answer is that if you're not very good at software development, it will be very difficult for you at this stage.  There are a lot of machine development frameworks built **on top** of tensorflow at this stage that are coalescing.
I have used ***tf-slim*** but others on my team like ***Keras***.  (That's probably my next adventure!)

Comment: BTW, tf-slim has many of the popular convolution models ready to go, whilst Keras has recently (a few weeks ago) merged a tf-only Keras version into the core.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.

1) Conventional econometrics is more interested in Statistical Inference than in Forecasting. The focus of tensorflow is forecasting (classification and regression). There are other good libraries in Python that you can focus on usual econometric issues. One of them is StatsModels.

2) Howerver, if your interest is on forecasting, it can be an option. However, I would not start using this library. I would try the "industrial" non-linear models provided by sklearn. There, you can find models that you can setup in few minutes and you can use them (at least) to gain intution about machine learning (the trade-off bias-variance, cross-validation, teste-set, validation and so on). Neural network models can be very difficult to sintonize for real world serious problems.

3) Before tensorflow you can also try Keras, which is a mask for tensorflow, where you can build a lot of interesting neural network models and also solve interesting problems.

4) The focus of tensorflow is in Deep Neural Networks. This is exactly the situation that you should consider to use it. With tensorflow you can really solve real world problems, but in order to that you need gain a lot of intuition in the process.